# PXGrid with Preview - Preview does not show up

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to show the preview text in one of my custom grid. This is similar to Activities tab on Case screen (CR306000). I have written below code but still it is not showing the preview text if I select Activities from the grid. Please suggest.

Code for DataView-

```html
[PXFilterable]

        [PXPreview(typeof(CRAcumaticaActivity))]

        [PXViewName("AcumaticaActivities")]

        public PXSelect<CRAcumaticaActivity,

        Where<CRAcumaticaActivity.cloud9CaseID, Equal<Current<CRCase.caseCD>>>,

        OrderBy<Desc<CRAcumaticaActivity.lastModifiedByDateTime>>> AcumaticaActivities;
```

HTML Code for gridwithpreview-

```html
<px:PXTabItem Text="Acumatica Activities" LoadOnDemand="True">
    <Template>
      <pxa:PXGridWithPreview runat="server" PrimaryViewControlID="form" PreviewPanelStyle="z-index: 100; background-color: Window" GridSkinID="Inquire" PreviewPanelSkinID="Preview" NoteField="" AllowSearch="True" BlankFilterHeader="All Acumatica Activities" MatrixMode="true" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="AcumaticaActivities" ID="grdAActivities" BorderWidth="0px" Width="100%">
        <AutoSize Enabled="True" MinWidth="100" MinHeight="100" />
        <ActionBar ActionsText="true" DefaultAction="AcuViewActivity" PagerVisible="False">
          <CustomItems>
            <px:PXToolBarButton Text="Get Activities">
              <AutoCallBack Target="ds" Command="GetActivities" /></px:PXToolBarButton>
            <px:PXToolBarButton Text="Publish Activity">
              <AutoCallBack Target="ds" Command="PublishActivity" /></px:PXToolBarButton></CustomItems></ActionBar>
        <GridMode AllowAddNew="False" AllowUpdate="False" AllowDelete="False" AllowFormEdit="False" AllowUpload="False" />
        <Levels>
          <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="AcumaticaActivities">
            <RowTemplate />
            <Columns>
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ActivityID" Visible="False" AllowShowHide="False" AutoCallBack="true" />
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Type" Width="250px" AutoCallBack="" />
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Summary" Width="20" LinkCommand="AcuViewActivity" Visible="" />
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Status" Width="50px" />
              <px:PXGridColumn DisplayFormat="g" DataField="StartDate" Width="90px" />
              <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Owner" Width="90px" /></Columns></px:PXGridLevel></Levels>
        <PreviewPanelTemplate>
          <px:PXHtmlView runat="server" DataField="Description" ID="edAcuDescrip" Height="100px" SkinID="Label" Width="100%">
            <AutoSize Enabled="true" Container="Parent" /></px:PXHtmlView></PreviewPanelTemplate>
        <CallbackCommands>
          <Refresh PostData="Page" CommitChanges="True" /></CallbackCommands></pxa:PXGridWithPreview></Template></px:PXTabItem></Items>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="100" MinWidth="300" ></AutoSize>
    </px:PXTab>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer and it is working now.

You should add `PXPreview` attribute to your Data View. In which first parameter should be your base DAC and second should be the child one.

For Example-

```html
[PXPreview(typeof(CRCase), typeof(CRAcumaticaActivity))]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to recreate your setup but there is too much involved to get it working completely.  However, I did notice that the DataField attribute on the `PXHtmlView` control is pointing to `Description`.  It may not make a difference, but try changing it to `description` with a lower-case D and see if that solves the problem.  I believe the DataField property needs to point to the class in the DAC and not the property itself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Tried with lower-case D for `description` but that did not worked unfortunately. Yes it is tricky to get a grid with preview.